# how to move the submit button to the right end in an inline form

Tags: css

I am not able to figure out how to move the Submit button to the right end of the form. As per the below code, my submit button is getting displayed before form control.

Here is my view

```
<div class="form-inline">
<%= form_for([@user, @user.categories.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Create Category" %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary col-xs-3" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is a CSS issues. Not a RoR issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="form-inline">
<%= form_for([@user, @user.categories.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Create Category" %>
    <span class="pull-right"><%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary col-xs-3" %></span>
<% end %>



.pull-right {
    float: right !important;
}
```